# Converting from literal escape sequence to represented character

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-literals

I'm attempting to read a desired line terminator from a configuration file.

If the parsing were working the way I want, the output from `print(val)` would be a blank line, and `print(repr(val))` would print `'\r'` because val would contain a carriage return character. Instead `print(val)` outputs `\r` and `print(repr(val))` outputs `'\\r'`, which I understand means val contains a backslash character and a 'r' character.

How do I convert from a string that contains literal representations of escape sequences to one that contains the characters those escape sequences represent?

Comment: `val.decode("string-escape")` works in Python 2.7, I don't have a 3.x installation handy to test if it still works.

Comment: It seems like it's "unicode-escape" in 3.x, and that worked thanks.